# Ajax Actionlink won't use POST, only GET (in ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried every solution I could find and nothing works. Here's the relevant code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Assign(int id)
{
    Person person = sc.GetPerson(id);
    if (person == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    ViewBag.PersonID = person.PersonID;
    ViewBag.FirstName = person.FirstName;
    ViewBag.LastName = person.LastName;
    ViewBag.PersonTitle = person.Title;

    List<Project> projects = sc.GetPersonNonAssignments(id).ToList();
    return View(projects);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Assign(int id, int id2)
{
    try
    {
        bool check = sc.CreateAssignment(id, id2);
        if (check)
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And in RouteConfig.cs I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here is the View (and it looks like I don't need type="text/javascript" in HTML5):

```
@model IEnumerable<TestService.Project>
@{ViewBag.Title = "Assign Person";}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
<h3>Assign @ViewBag.FirstName @ViewBag.LastName (@ViewBag.PersonTitle) to:</h3>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)</td>
        <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Assign", "Assign", new { id=ViewBag.PersonID, id2=item.ProjectID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
@{string linkname = "Back to " + @ViewBag.FirstName + "'s projects";}
<p>@Html.ActionLink(linkname, "Details", new { id=ViewBag.PersonID })</p>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to People", "Index")</p>
```

In the root Web.config I have:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

And just for good measure, in Global.asax, I have:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

It still will not POST, only GET. I've verified this by stripping the [HttpPost] and renaming the second ActionResult. I've tried "Inspect element" in Chrome, it doesn't find any errors. What is going on?

Comment: Turns out I don't actually need it to post, get will do what I want, but I still really want to know why it won't post.

Comment: Just to fill out the full overload, can you try adding a null after the ajaxoptions declaration for the html attributes property and see if that works, i noticed in some places the order of the overloads can shift, it might be that.

Comment: You mean like:
@Ajax.ActionLink("Assign2", "Assign", new { id=ViewBag.PersonID, id2=item.ProjectID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, null)
? Didn't fix it. Also tried:
@Ajax.ActionLink("Assign2", "Assign", new { id=ViewBag.PersonID, id2=item.ProjectID }, null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })

Comment: Also having this problem, still no solution?